# Server 2003/2008 Redundancy Possibility

Tags: windows-server-2008

I was wondering if you are running your primary DC, DNS and DHCP off of Server 2003, can you create a backup DC and DNS running Server 2008 R2 if my main DC and DNS are Server 2003?

So to be more detailed

Server 1 runs Server 2003, and is the main DC with DNS DHCP and Active Directory running on it.

Server 2: Server 2008 with no roles or anything (would like to make this one the backup)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Promote the 2008 server and add rolls.  You will need to look at DHCP as you don't want two servers handing out IPs from the same range of the subnet.  You can split the IP range easily

Comment: So what youre saying is if I create the 2008 server as a DC, it will overtake the 2003 server as the primary DC?  So the 2003 DC will no longer be the primary, correct?

Comment: It will not take anything over automatically. And there is no such thing as primary DC, the closest thing to that is PDC emulator FSMO role, and 2003 will remain to hold that role unless you explicitly move it to 2008.